# Python repeated list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to do a vigenere cipher (or something similar) for my GCSE work. However one problem I have come across is that my list index is always out of range, yet the code I have is exactly the same as when I had it before and there were no errors. This is my code:

```
#Encrypting
def encrypt():
     #>Creating initial variables
     plainText = str(input('Input your plain text \n --> ')).upper()
     key = str(input('Input your key. Make sure it is as long as your plain text. \n --> ')).upper()

    #>Looping key
    if len(key) < len(plainText):
        key = len(plainText)*key
    else:
        key = key

    #>Creating lists for ASCII values of each letter
    plainAscii=[ord(i) for i in plainText]
    keyAscii=[ord(k) for k in key]

    #>Shortening the keyAscii list
    while len(keyAscii) != len(plainAscii):
        keyAscii.pop(len(keyAscii) - 1)

    #>Adding the values together and putting them into a new list
    cipherAscii=[]
    x = 0
    while x < len(key):
        item = (plainAscii[x] + keyAscii[x]) - 75
        cipherAscii.append(item)
        x = x + 1

    #>Making sure all numbers are within the 65 - 90 window

    newCipher=[]
    for c in cipherAscii:
        if c > 90:
            c = c - 26
            newCipher.append(c)
        elif c < 65:
            c = c + 26
            newCipher.append(c)
        else:
            newCipher.append(c)

    #>Converting the ASCII back into regular letters
    cipherText=[chr(i) for i in newCipher]

    #>Printing the cipher text
    for i in cipherText:
        print (i, end="")
```

Is my code wrong? Please help soon as I do not have a lot of time.

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us the line where the issue happens

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the full error Traceback and pointed out precisely which line the last line number in it corresponds to. Also, give sample input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: What is `key = len(plainText)*key` supposed to do? If you want to trim the key to the length of the plain text, use `key ` key[:len(plaintext)]`

Comment: On the 

    #>Adding the values together and putting them into a new list
    cipherAscii=[]
    x = 0
    while x < len(key):
        item = (plainAscii[x] + keyAscii[x]) - 75
        cipherAscii.append(item)
        x = x + 1

Comment: Just for the item = (plainAscii[x] + keyAscii[x]) - 75 sorry

Comment: @CharlieBewsey that's six lines of code. The error is going to report only one line. Edit your answer to address these comments (full error Traceback, sample input, expected vs. actual output, etc.) or this will likely be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: And [edit] all additional information you give in comments into your question as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that my previous answer is wrong, so I'm posting a new one...

The problem is not with the way you are padding the key, it is much simpler: You pad `key` *a lot*, then create an ASCII-version of the key, `keyAscii`, trim *that* version to the correct length, but then *loop* for each character in the still much longer `key`.

To fix it, all you really have to do is change your loop condition to

```
while x < len(keyAscii):
```

or trim the `key` to the correct length *before* converting to ASCII:

```
# trim after padding
if len(key) > len(plainText):
    key = key[:len(plainText)]
```

Also, you don't need to pad the key quite as much: As noted in another (now deleted) answer, you just have to repeat the key `ceil(len(text)/len(key))` times, i.e.

```
key = key * int(math.ceil(len(text)/len(key)))
```

---

Also, you could make you function a lot simpler by using `itertools.cycle` and `zip`:

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key):
    cipherText = ((p + q) - 75 for (p, q) in zip(map(ord, plaintext), 
                                                 map(ord, itertools.cycle(key))))
    cipherText = ((c - 65) % 26 + 65 for c in cipherText)
    return ''.join(map(chr, cipherText))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this part:

```
if len(key) < len(plainText):
    key = len(plainText)*key
```

By multiplying the `key` with `len(plainText)`, you repeat the key. This causes a problem later, in your loop, where `x` can get much larger than `len(plainText)`

```
while x < len(key):
    item = (plainAscii[x] + keyAscii[x]) - 75
```

Instead, you want to trim the key to the same length as the plain text.

```
if len(key) < len(plainText):
    key = key[:len(plainText)]
```

Simple demo:

```
>>> 3 * "abcde"
'abcdeabcdeabcde'
>>> "abcde"[:3]
'abc'
```